# Connect to remote Windows machine: Network error: Connection timed out

Tags: microsoft-windows, tramp, remote

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1

When I want to connect to remote Windows machine (via VPN) I use the next steps:

- Start application OpenVPN and success connect
- Start msc (Remote Desktop Connection)
- Input ip address (193.178.6.32)

As result I success connect to remote Windows machine. OK.

So I want to connect to same remote Windows machine by Emacs.

My steps in Emacs:

- Find file (**C-x C-f**)
- /193.178.6.32:

But I get error on buffer ***tramp/pscp 193.178.6.32***

```
plink   -ssh -t 193.178.6.32 " env 'TERM=dumb' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=#$ ' /bin/sh " && exit || exit
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

Tramp does not support connecting a remote MS Windows host from a local MS Windows host.

Comment: IMHO, a Windows host running [KpyM ssh daemon](http://www.kpym.com/2/kpym/index.htm) might allow TRAMP connections to it because KpyM is both Windows native and totally SSH compliant. I've tried tramping to a Windows box running KpyM ssh daemon and it failed on the last step, it said: **tramp-open-shell # Opening remote shell ‘/bin/sh’...failed** It looks to be about `sh.exe` not being available on the host. I reckon if I can make `sh.exe` run on the host when ssh connection is made, then I think Tramp would work, too.

Comment: Perhaps it would work. I don't know whether sh.exe is compatible to POSIX shells (that's mandatory), but even in case: there are several other commands needed on the remote side to make Tramp happy.